# How to use AzureCliCredential when authenticating via Keyvault through "EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi" in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0, azure-keyvault, msal

When I access a secret or certificate from Keyvault, I use ChainedTokenCredential.
This makes sure that for local development, the AzureCLI is used to obtain a token for Keyvault and in production scenarios a service principal:

```
    var tokenCredential = new ChainedTokenCredential(
        new AzureCliCredential(),
        new DefaultAzureCredential());

    _ = tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://vault.azure.net/.default" })).Result;
    
    _secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyvaultOptions.Value.KeyVaultUrl), tokenCredential, _secretClientOptions);
```

This works fine and has the main purpose of speeding up the keyvault access like explained [here](https://anthonysimmon.com/defaultazurecredential-local-development-optimization/).

However, I have no idea how to make use of the AzureCliCredential when I am using ASP.NET and I want to call a downstream API through ITokenAcquisition.

Probably the configuration can be done in this piece of code when setting up the authentication of downstream APIs:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
                {
                    //Do something???
                })
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

There must be a way how to improve the keyvault performance also here and avoid unnecessary calls.